# Does inflation erode stock earnings or are stocks a good inflation hedge? - Intelligent Investor Book Question

Tags: stocks, inflation

I've come across this in the beginning of the book "The Intelligent Investor", by Benjamin Graham:

> How well did Graham’s forecast pan out? At first blush, it seems, very
> well: From the beginning of 1972 through the end of 1981, stocks earned
> an annual average return of 6.5%. (Graham did not specify the time period
> for his forecast, but it’s plausible to assume that he was thinking of a 10-
> year time horizon.) **However, inflation raged at 8.6% annually over this
> period, eating up the entire gain that stocks produced.** In this section of his
> chapter, Graham is summarizing what is known as the “Gordon equation,”
> which essentially holds that the stock market’s future return is the sum of the
> current dividend yield plus expected earnings growth. With a dividend yield
> of just under 2% in early 2003, and long-term earnings growth of around
> 2%, **plus inflation at a bit over 2%**, a future average annual return of roughly
> 6% is plausible. (See the commentary on Chapter 3.)

It looks like in the first bold sentence, inflation is **taking** from the stock's returns, but in the second it's being **added**!

Could you help me make sense of this?

Thank you for taking the time to read so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second bolded statement the returns are being broken down into the dividend yield, the company growth and inflation. This is why the 2% dividend yield plus 2% inflation plus 2% company growth makes the 6% total. Inflation is the change of the value of money over time so is always part of any return over a period - it is the change in the value of money over that time. That means that the 6% is nominal (with inflation included) return. If the total return were 5% and dividends and inflation were both 2% when the company must have only grown by 1% - the other 1% has been consumed by inflation. If inflation were at 1% and total return back at 6% then (real) company growth must have been 3% (in the starting year's prices).

In the first bolded statement inflation was running at 8.6% which means that, using the same equation as an example, if dividend yield plus company growth plus 8.6% for inflation must be equal to 6% (the nominal return) then the real (after inflation) return is -2.6% because the effect of inflation. Recall that inflation affects the value of all money no matter what you do and is not a return that you receive. In fact inflation erodes the value of money that isn't producing a return - I can buy less with $1 in a year's time than I can now.

Comment: Oh so when he said, in the footnote, that the long-term earnings growth are around 2% (right before the 2nd bold) -- he could have said that the nominal earnings are around 4%. Is that correct? That would have made it more compatible with the 1st bold and it wouldn't have confused me haha!

Comment: @user5646514 I think that he *should* have said nominal rather than could have - it would make it much easier to read. Unfortunately only Economists are really all that clear on the difference.

Comment: I'll remember that next time I get confused about inflation-related things. Thanks for helping me :)